# How do I calculate certain angles determined by sides and diagonals of a regular octagon?

Tags: geometry

I have this exercise:

[image]

My development was:

$\angle{\beta} = 135°$, because this is a regular polygon.

$\angle{y} = 135° - 22.5° = 112.5°$, because the triangle $AGH$ is isosceles, then its equal angles are $22.5$, then $y + 22.5° = 135°$.

But I could not find the $\angle{\alpha} $. How could I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\angle \alpha = 90^\circ$ as $\bar{AB} || \bar{FE}$ and symmetry.

Comment: In all regular polygon, the opposite sides are parallel?

Comment: ...in a regular *octagon* (or $2n$-gon) such as in your figure, yes.

Comment: What you mean with $2n$ gon

Comment: Think about it.... what do you think "$2n$-gon" means?  (Recall pentagon, hexagon, heptagon, octagon, ...)

Comment: I think that the number of sides is divisible by 2

Comment: Bingo!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks David G.Stork :D

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you inscribe the octagon into a circle, $\angle{\alpha}$ is the angle in a semi circle  $= 90^\circ$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your anser, can you provide me an image to better understanding, please ?

Comment: @Mattiu See edited answer.

Comment: @Mattiu This is known as Thale's theorem, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

In a regular $n$-gon the internal angle is  $(n-2)\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{n}$. For the regular octagon this is then $(8-2)\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{8}=6\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{8}=135^{\circ}$.

Hence $\beta = 135^{\circ}$. Now since $\triangle AHG$ is isosceles, then $\angle HAG=\angle HGA=22.5^{\circ}$. Therefore the ratio of the angles $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\alpha$ is

$$\beta:\gamma:\alpha=135:135-22.5:135-2\times 22.5=135:112.5:90=6:5:4$$

So $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90^{\circ}+135^{\circ}+112.5^{\circ}=337.5^{\circ}$.

In general if you dissect a regular polygon into triangles in the manner of the question the ratio of the angles is as
$$(n-2):(n-3):\dots:2:1$$

Comment: Why does that ratio work? Is it only when triangles are formed from the same vertex?

Comment: @Mattiu One could probably give lots of reasons, but one is the interior angle theorem. The polygon is inscribed in a circle and each side subtends an equal angle at the center, so each subtends an equal angle at a vertex (except, of course, for the sides adjacent to that vertex).

Answer (score 1):

Any regular polygon of any number of sides can be inscribed in a circle.
The figure below shows what might be a few of the vertices 
($A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$) 
and sides of a regular polygon inscribed in a circle.

[image]

Now if these are vertices of a regular $n$-gon, we can continue the sequence around the circle until we get back to $A.$
Then we will have $n$ equal sides of the polygon, and together with the center of the circle each side forms an isoceles triangle
($\triangle AOB$, $\triangle BOC$, $\triangle COD$, etc.).
These triangles are all congruent, and their angles at $O$ sum to $360$ degrees, so each of these angles is $\frac{360}{n}$ degrees.

But the inscribed angle subtended by two points on a circle
is half as large as the central angle subtended by those same points;
that is, $\angle BAC$ is half as large as $\angle BOC,$
or to put it another way, $\angle BOC = 2\angle BAC.$
If we let $\theta = \angle BAC,$ then $\angle BOC = 2\theta,$
as shown in the figure.

But $\angle BOC$ is one of the vertex angles of the $n$ congruent isoceles triangles, that is,
$$ 2\theta = \angle BOC = \left(\frac{360}{n}\right)^\circ,$$
so $\theta = \left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^\circ.$

Since the central angles $\angle BOC$, $\angle COD$, $\angle DOE$, and so forth are all equal, so are the inscribed angles $\angle BAC$, $\angle CAD$, $\angle DAE$, and so forth.
That is,
$$ \angle BAC = \angle CAD = \angle DAE = \cdots = \theta. $$

It follows that
\begin{align}
 \angle BAD &= \angle BAC + \angle CAD = 2\theta, \\
 \angle BAE &= \angle BAC + \angle CAD + \angle DAE = 3\theta,
\end{align}
and so forth.
In other words, if the inscribed angle at $A$ subtends $k$ sides of the polygon, the angle is $k\theta.$

In a regular octagon, $n = 8$ (eight sides), so
$\theta = \left(\frac{180}{8}\right)^\circ = 22.5^\circ.$
In your figure, $\beta$ subtends six sides of the octagon,
$\gamma$ subtends five sides, and $\alpha$ subtends four sides, so
\begin{align}
\beta  &= (n-2)\theta = 6\theta = 135^\circ, \\
\gamma &= (n-3)\theta = 5\theta = 112.5^\circ, \\
\alpha &= (n-4)\theta = 4\theta = 90^\circ.
\end{align}

If you had drawn a regular polygon with more than eight sides,
and drawn segments from vertex $A$ to each other vertex,
the angles $\beta,$ $\gamma,$ and $\alpha$ formed in this way would
still measure $(n-2)\theta,$ $(n-3)\theta,$ $(n-4)\theta,$ and so forth.

Comment: I was working on a proof and you beat me to it, (+1) for a lovely graphic too!

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that the inscribed angle is half of the centra angle opposite to the same arc.

Thus, $$\alpha\overset{m}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat {ABCDE}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 360^o \cdot \frac{4}{8};$$
$$\beta\overset{m}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat {ABCDEFG}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 360^o \cdot \frac{6}{8};$$
$$\gamma\overset{m}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat {ABCDEF}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 360^o \cdot \frac{5}{8}.$$
As a result, $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 360^o \cdot\frac{4+6+5}{8}=337.5^o.$$

Comment: Thanks, but i need an answer without use circumference's properties.

Comment: @Mattiu: You should put that kind of restriction in the problem statement. We're mathematicians, not mind-readers. ;) (BTW: This is the answer I would've given.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Because $\angle AHG = \angle FGH$ and $AH = FG$, then $AHGF$ is an isosceles trapezoid with $AF$ parallel to $HG$. Note that$$
β = \angle AHG = \angle HGF = \angle GFE,
$$
thus$$
\angle AFG = π - \angle HGF = π - β\\
\Longrightarrow α = \angle AFE = \angle GFE - \angle AFG = 2β - π = \frac{π}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you provide an image to a better understand, please?

Comment: @Mattiu I've renamed the vertices according to the graph.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Just about to post a similar solution, but you beat me to it! +1.

Comment: So for any quadrilateral, a minimum requisit for be a trapezoid is a pair of sides equal and two angles equal?

Answer (score 1):

Since the octagon is regular it can be inscribed in a circle as following

[image]

We can see that $\alpha$ is opposite of the diameter of the circle so is $90\text{ degrees}$ ans the summation would be$$\LARGE \alpha+\beta+\gamma=337.5\text{ degrees}$$

(picture from http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43400/43451/8c_43451.htm with some modifications)

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, soo easy now!

Comment: You're welcome :) I wish you luck......

Comment: Are you assuming that the $AE $ segment passes through the center of the circle, where is the proof of that?

Answer (score 0):

First: $\angle{GFA}=135^\circ-a.$ $\angle{GAF}=180^\circ-135^\circ+a-112.5^\circ=-67.5+a.$  (interior angle sum & triangle angle usm)
 $\angle{HAF}=\angle{HAG}+\angle{GAF}$ (angle addition property) is equal to $45^\circ.$ Attached is an image of an octagon that might help you believe the fact.[image]

If we draw in a square, as shown, it is evident $\angle{HAF}$ is $45^\circ.$

[image]
These triangles are congruent by SSS (all sides are the same). Therefore, the corresponding angles are the same. This means twice $\angle{HAF}=90^\circ,$ implying $\angle{HAF}=45^\circ.$

$\angle{HAG}=\frac{180^\circ-135^\circ}2=22.5^\circ$ (isosceles property & triangle angle sum).
Therefore, $-67.5^\circ+a+22.5^\circ=45^\circ$ which leads to $a=90^\circ.$

Comment: Thanks, I could understand that:
$\angle{GAF} + 67.5 = \angle{\alpha}$, but my problem is to understand how you know that $\angle{HAF}$ is equal to $45º$ ?

Comment: Okay, I just realized this. If you complete the square (not as in algebra, but trace the other half on all the segments $ED,CB,AH,GF$ then you get a square. Since it is the same triangle you have before, $2\angle{HAF}=90^\circ.$ This leads to $\angle{HAF}=45^\circ.$

Comment: But, how do you know that a square will be formed? In fact, with two scalene triangles we could not do it, then you assume that they are isosceles before forming the squares.

Comment: We rely on two facts only: $\overline{FA}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{CH}$, the triangle is isosceles. For being isosceles, we can reflect it on its line of symmetry and it would be the same (the line  that goes through the midpoints of $\overline{HA}$ and $\overline{ED}.$  As for the other triangle, we can just rotate the triangle bound by $\overline{FA},\overline{CH},\overline{HA}.$ Surely, this is hard to understand, so just tell me about the part you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Already i understood this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer based on using the cosine rule.

In a regular $n$-gon the internal angle is  $(n-2)\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{n}$. For the regular octagon this is then $(8-2)\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{8}=6\times\frac{180^{\circ}}{8}=135^{\circ}$. Hence $\beta = 135^{\circ}$, and since $\triangle AHG$ is isosceles, it follows $\angle HAG=\angle HGA=22.5^{\circ}$, and so $\gamma=135^{\circ}-22.5^{\circ}=112.5^{\circ}$.

As the octagon is regular each side is the same length, say $a$. Hence in $\triangle AHG$, $AH=GF=a$, and let $AG=b$. Then by the cosine rule 
\begin{align*}
b^2&=2a^2-2a^2\cos\,135^{\circ}\\
&=2a^2(1-\cos\,135^{\circ})\\
&=2a^2\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
&=a^2\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Hence 
$$b=a\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\tag{1}$$
Now let $AF=c$, then by the cosine rule and knowing $\angle AGF=\gamma=112.5^{\circ}$,
\begin{align*}
c^2&=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\,112.5^{\circ}\\
&=a^2+a^2(2+\sqrt{2})-2a^2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\\
&=a^2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)\\
\end{align*}
since $\cos\,112.5^{\circ}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$.

So
$$c=a\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}\tag{2}$$
Now let $AE=d$ and use the cosine rule again
\begin{align*}
d^2&=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\,\alpha\\
&=a^2+a^2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)
-2a^2\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}\cos\,\alpha\\
&=a^2\left(4+2\sqrt{2}\right)
-2a^2\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}\cos\,\alpha\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
Now $AG=GE=b$, and $\angle HGF=135^{\circ}$, with  $\angle HGA=\angle FGE=22.5^{\circ}$, so $\angle AGE=135^{\circ}-2\times22.5^{\circ}=90^{\circ}$. Using the cosine rule again
\begin{align*}
d^2&=2b^2-2b^2\cos\,90^{\circ}\\
&=2b^2\\
&=2a^2(2+\sqrt{2})\tag{4}
\end{align*}
where we have used $(1)$: $b=a\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$.

Therefore plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$ gives
\begin{align*}
2a^2(2+\sqrt{2})&=a^2\left(4+2\sqrt{2}\right)-2a^2\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}\cos\,\alpha\tag{5}\\
\end{align*}
and on rearranging $(5)$:
\begin{align*}
\cos\,\alpha&=
\frac{a^2\left(4+2\sqrt{2}\right)-2a^2(2+\sqrt{2})}
{2a^2\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}}\\
&=
\frac{4+2\sqrt{2}-4-2\sqrt{2}}
{2\sqrt{\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}}\\
&=0
\tag{6}\\
\end{align*}
Therefore $(6)$ implies
$$\alpha=\cos^{-1}(0)=90^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind just five basic things in filling up all angles.

- All segments subtend $\pi/8= 22.5^{\circ}$ at A (equal segments subtend equal agle at center. Corresponding angle subtended at boundary is half that.
- Every external angle is  $\pi/4= 45^{\circ}$ at each vertex $ = 2 \pi/8$rotation between sides
- Sum of three angles in triangle is $\pi= 180^{\circ}$
- Complementary angles sum to $\pi/4= 45^{\circ}$
- Angle in semi-circle $\pi/2= 90^{\circ}$

Required angle sum

$$ 337.5^{\circ}  $$

[image: AngleChaseOctagon]